# $(window).on('load', function.... doesn't fire on a different server with same browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-history

I have simple javascript code to intercept the back button using the history API and then give a popup prompt, as seen all over the web.  Works in Chrome when viewing my MVC pages from localhost.   When I publish to the test server, it doesn't work.

```
if (window.history && history.pushState) {
            $(window).on('load', function () {
                history.pushState(null, null, null);
                $(window).on('popstate', function () {
                    var stayOnPage = confirm("You clicked the back button");
                    if (!stayOnPage) {
                        history.pushState(null, null, null);
                    } else {
                        history.back();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

What is NOT happening on the test server is that it is not ever capturing the "load" event of the window when I change pages.  I know this by putting "debugger" statements all through that block.  On localhost, it captures the event, then calls history.pushState() and is able to wire up the "popstate" event handler.   Then when I click the back button it shows the confirm popup.
But on the test server, it never calls history.pushState() because it never captures the load event.  I'm using the same Chrome browser for both sites, but only the localhost works.   No idea why it would change.  And the test server isn't changing origins on calls.   It's all MVC with a root url of the format:
http://FullyQualifiedMachineName:84/User/UserDetails
(machine name with the fully qualified domain and a port number)

Comment: This looks like it should have a jQuery or Node tag.

Comment: try $(window).on('load', () => { if (window.history && history.pushState) {

Comment: Okay, I changed the function declaration as you suggested.   It continues to work on the localhost as expected.  The load event handler now fires on the test server ONLY on the initial page load.   But the localhost "load" event handler fires every time I change to a different page.  The test server only ever fires once.  But here's another twist:  I used the anonymous function declaration in my "popstate" handler assignment and then the test server no longer even hit the "load" event handler on the initial load.  I've tested multiple times and it is repeatable behavior.

Comment: I decided to push this to our production server and it works.  I even went back to the original code and it also works.  So maybe the fully qualified domain machine name and/or port has something to do with it.   Thank you for your suggestion, it helped me to refine my thinking.